# Why am I getting this DataStage job compilation errors?

Tags: datastage

I am getting the following error along with a lot of others when trying to compile jobs on DataStage 11.7:

Error when checking composite operator: Subprocess command failed with exit status 256

I did an internet search of all possible solutions. Could not look at dsxchange as the site is down. Looked at all compiler options and they look the same as other projects with successful compilation.

IBM has a solution but it did not work for me:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.3.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.trouble.ref.doc/topics/transformstage01.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are 165 hits on DSXchange (it is not down).
Can you please verify your operating system and the values of the four environment variables that control your compiler and linker (APT_COMPILER, APT_COMPILEOPT, APT_LINKER and APT_LINKEROPT)?  Please also verify the exact version of DataStage that you are running and the exact version of the compiler.
As noted in the Knowledge Center article, this error usually relates to the compiler being incompatible, the incorrect version, or having incorrect options.